# Making a rotation around a point

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using THREE API in order to realize some animations in my app. Now i have a real problem : i'd like making spherical rotation around a specific point. The "rotate" method included in mesh objects allow me to make them, but the center of the rotation is (by default i guess) the center of the mesh.
Then, i only rotate my objects around themself... 
I have already found some examples, but they don't solve my problem. I tried to create objects 3D parents like groups, and tried to make the rotation around this groups after having translated them, but this still does not work...

Can you please give me a hand about that ?

Comment: Since you have tried all these solutions it would be best if you could create a jsfiddle so we can take a look at the problem in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so sorry, i found my problem... Making a jsfiddle made me realize i forgot to instanciate my parent as " a new Object 3D() ", that was why i didn't see any objects in my scene when i used animation on my parent... i give you a short part of my code anyway dedicated to interested people finding any help :

```
// mesh
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
parent = new THREE.Object3D();
parent.add(mesh);
// if i want my rotation point situated at (300;0;0)
parent.position.set(300,0,0);
mesh.position.set(-300, 0, 0);
scene.add(parent);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KqTg8/6/
Thank you